# import keypair to an existing pkcs12 keystore under a new alias name

Tags: ssl, tomcat, oauth-2.0, openssl, keystore

I am learning OAUTH2 and OpenID Connect and configuring multiply tomcat servers (a Client for the UI, and multiply Resource Servers for the APIs) to use SSL. So I have created a PKCS12 keystore with a self-signed certificate + private key the following way and then I pushed it under my 1st Tomcat:

*(I know that the commands bellow can be simplify and combine into one (or two) but I deliberately keep tem separately because that way I can see and understand the steps better)*

**(1) The keypair was created with openssl this way:**

```
openssl genrsa \
        -des3 \
        -passout pass:$phrase \
        -out id_rsa_$domain.key $numbits
```

**(2) Then I created a Certificate Signing Request with this command:**

```
openssl req \
        -new \
        -key id_rsa_$domain.key \
        -passin pass:$phrase \
        -subj "$subj" \
        -out $domain.csr
```

**(3) After that I created a x509 certificate:**

```
openssl x509 \
        -req \
        -days $days \
        -in $domain.csr \
        -signkey id_rsa_$domain.key \
        -passin pass:$phrase \
        -out $domain.crt
```

**(4) Finnaly I have created a key-store in PKCS12 format:**

```
pem=$domain.pem
cat id_rsa_$domain.key > $pem
cat $domain.crt >> $pem

openssl pkcs12 \
        -export \
        -in $pem \
        -passin pass:$phrase \
        -password pass:$keystore_pwd \
        -name $domain \
        -out example.com.pkcs12
rm $pem
```

At the end of this process I have the following files:

- **id_rsa_authserver.example.com.key**: the private (and public) key
- **authserver.example.com.crt**: the self signed certificate
- **example.com.pkcs12**: the keystore

Inside the .pkcs12 file I only have one key-pair entry under the `authserver.example.com` alias. I have checked the result with `KeyStore Explorer` as well and everything looks fine and the 1st Tomcat works properly with that keystore.

Then I repeated the steps (1), (2) and (3) and I generated new files for `order.example.com` host machine and at the end I have two new files:

- **id_rsa_order.example.com.key**
- **order.example.com.crt**

Now I would like to add to my "root" `example.com.pkcs12` keystore this new keypair + certificate under the `order.example.com` alias in order to I keep all certs that I use for my demo in one keystore. I can do it easily with the `KeyStore Explorer` tool via the `tools > import key pair > openSSL > browse the private key and cert files`, but this is not enough good for me. I would like to do the import via command line using OpenSSL.

Unfortunately I have not found the proper openssl command that I can use to ADD my 2nd key+cert to the existing keystore.

What is the command that I can use?

Comment: Commandline OpenSSL can't create a PKCS12 containing more than one privatekey. What you can do is create two separate PKCS12s using `openssl pkcs12 -export` and then use Java `keytool -importkeystore` to copy one of them into the other (or a copy of the other). PS: if it matters, the certs you create with this process don't have SAN and thus won't be accepted by Chrome, even if they are in (you add them to) the truststore.

Comment: I accept your response as a solution if you post it. Thx

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work directly.

After you created key and certifificate using openssl, you create a new temporarily pkcs12 key store using openssl.

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in my.crt -inkey my.key -out my.p12 -name myAlias -passin file:myInPasswordFile -passout file:myOutPasswordFile
```

Then you merge the new temp keystore into the existing one using keytool:

```
keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass:file destKeyStorePasswordFile -destkeystore destination.p12 -srckeystore my.p12 -deststoretype PKCS12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass:file myOutPasswordFile -alias myAlias
```